# Redirect from HTTPS to HTTP without URL rewrites

Tags: iis, https

We have a Windows Server 2008 with IIS. One of the sub domains (i.e. HTTPS.TEST.COM) is bound to https and the other sub domain is bound to http (i.e. HTTP.TEST.COM). If the user enters https://HTTP.TEST.COM the user gets an ugly error about incorrect certificate - for some reason IIS uses the certificate for HTTPS.TEST.COM because user typed https instead of http.

My question is, how do I make sure visits to https://HTTP.TEST.COM gets redirected to http://HTTP.TEST.COM? It is not necessary to redirect to same sub page, the important thing is to get rid of the ugly error message. I have seen other posts about URL rewrites, but I get the feeling there are easier ways to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible, because when the client first connects to the **https** port of the server, there is an SSL handshake that results in the server certificate being presented to the client **before** the client is even allowed to tell the server which URL it is trying to access.

It is the client that gives the error that the server certificate for does not match what is expected and this happens before the server can do a redirect to the correct subdomain.

However, if you place a wildcard certificate for `*.test.com` on the server, you can effectively bypass the error and get the redirection to work. Another way would be to have separate SSL certificates for both `HTTP.TEST.COM` and `HTTPS.TEST.COM`, but for the above reasons you must then have them on separate IP addresses.